# htaccess redirect everything inside folder to no-www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect a specific folder and ALL of it content from "www.domain.com/myfolder/" to "domain.com/myfolder/". That folder contains more folders.

I've tried including this `.htaccess` file to the folder, with no success.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/myfolder/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But only redirects "www.domain.com/myfolder/" to "domain.com/myfolder/".

If I access to "domain.com/myfolder/something/" (index of *something* folder) or "domain.com/myfolder/something/whatever" (file inside *something* folder) isn't working, it throws 404 error.

Maybe using some regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^folder/ http://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

Comment: Then the file should be inside `/myfolder`?

Comment: No, it goes in your root folder's htaccess.